# How to get power in dependent voltage source?

Tags: power, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]l've made a simple circuit using Thevenin's theorem, and then help me which node to formulate to solve the problem.

(I've written Thevenin's theorem, am I writing it correctly?)

Also, Vx is a voltage source, how do you get power from it? I learned to know resistance to save power.

Comment: does Vx means Va ?

Answer (score 0):

1) What's the voltage across the \$\small 8\Omega\$ resistor?

2) Hence, what's the current through the horizontal \$\small 6\Omega\$ resistor?

3) Where does this current flow when it leaves the \$\small 6\Omega\$ resistor?

4) Hence, what voltage must the dependent source be providing?